# Unable to detect when app is reentered from background other than onStop method?

Tags: android

I want to refresh the app screen whenever user minimizes the app and reopens it from background. The issue is that if i apply my logic in onStop method then it will be called in that case too when i open another activity on top of existing page when app is open. In iOS there is a method that informs them when app is re-entered from background but how can i achieve this in android?

Answer (score 2):

You should use OnResume().

There is the famous graph taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) that might help you.
[image]

If you would like to know if the `OnResume()` is called after onStart or `onPause()`, have a boolean flag in your activity like:

```
void onPause () {
    bPaused = true;
}

void onResume() {

    //check the bPaused member
    if (bPaused == true){
        bPaused = false; // reset the flag
        //do what ever you want to do as the app was resumed
    } else {
        // we are entring this code after onStart and onPaused was not called yet.
    }

}
```

Comment: but that is called even when activity/fragment is firsttime created or user returns from next activity. I want to get alert only when app is re-entered from minimized state and nothing else

Comment: If the code sample helped you please accept the answer.  If not what else is missing?

Comment: I used to onTrimMemory in Application class with level 'TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN'  to detect that.
Thanks for your solution as well but was meant to detect that at app level.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution :)